# How to merge two models into one model with django for admin?

Tags: python, django

I have to identical models:

```
class AnimalGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)    
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/groups")

class AnimalSubGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)  
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/groups")
```

and they have a on-to-many relationship. So AnimalGroup can have multiple AnimalSubGroups

But as you see they have identical fields.

Question: how to make one model of this?

So that in Admin I can create animalgroups, like:

- mammals
- fish

And then I can create the subgroups. Like

- bigCat and then I select mammals.

Comment: SubGroups cannot have subgroups of their own?

Comment: You can use [Model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Comment: @user2390182. What exactly do you mena?

Comment: I mean for the Django admin

Comment: I mean if there are are only two levels of groups, or do you want to be able to have complete group hierarchy of any number of levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an abstract base model:

```
class NameDescImageModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)    
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/groups')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class AnimalGroup(NameDescImageModel):
    pass

class AnimalSubGroup(NameDescImageModel):
    group = models.ForeignKey(AnimalGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: #Willem Van Onsem  .Oke, but the data will then be saved in just one table? Like a self reference

Comment: @mightycodeNewton: no, this is an *abstract* base table: it will create two models with the fields defined in `NameDescImageModel`, that model at the top will *not* result in database table.

Answer (score 3):

Have them inherit an abstract base class and give the subgroup an additional foreign key:

```
class AbstractAnimalGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)    
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/groups")
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AnimalGroup(AbstractAnimalGroup):
    pass

class AnimalSubGroup(AbstractAnimalGroup):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(AnimalGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you want subgroups to be actual AnimalGroups, you can use [multi-table inheritence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

```
class AnimalGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)    
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/groups")

class AnimalSubGroup(AnimalGroup):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(AnimalGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, all AnimalSubGroups will be also contained in `AnimalGroup.objects.all()`.

Comment: We had both the same idea about adding a parent foreign key :)

Comment: How else could you reasonably model a one2many relation.

Comment: @user2390182. Oke, and then in admin I just register  AbstractAnimalGroup?

Comment: @user2390182. But how to register then for admin?

Comment: @user2390182 But then data will be saved then in still two tables. Not just one table?

Comment: Yes, the ASG table will have an implicit one-to-one field `animalgroup_ptr` to get the AG instance, but the AG fields can be accessed directly from the ASG  object.